# Copy Specific values in a column

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I need some VBA help. I want to copy values in a column. 
Referencing to the picture, I want to start to copy when the value is "Dept/Branch code: 144" because this is the only value is consistent and stop copying until the cell value is "Total". Please help!!!! I cant use range to copy because te range might not be consistent in other workbook.

[image: Excel Data]

```
Sub Copycolumn()
For i = 1 To 100
If Left(Cells(i, "A").Value, 21) = ("Dept/Branch code: 144") Then
Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to save the positions of the cells in the new list

```
Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=Range("C" & i)
```

and if you want to make the cells in a new list then your code should be like this:

```
Sub Copycolumn()
n = 0
For i = 1 To 100
If Left(Cells(i, "A").Value, 21) = ("Dept/Branch code: 144") Then
n = n + 1
Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=Range("C" & n)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range! The following code will find the first row to start the copy, then use that to look for the first instance of "Total*", then copy that range to cell C1

```
Sub gogo()
    START_ROW = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Dept/Branch code: 144*", Range("A:A"), 0)
    END_ROW = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total*", Range("A" & START_ROW & ":A5000"), 0) + START_ROW - 1
    Range("A" & START_ROW & ":A" & END_ROW).Copy
    Range("C1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

This code doesn't use any looping, it just utilises Excel's in-built super-fast function for finding a MATCH so it'd be much faster if you had a sheet that had a tonne of entries

Also please note it's using a wild card * at the end of "Total" and "Dept/Branch code: 144" to do the match so you don't have to strip the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Range` object, you can use the `Find` function to find the first cell where `"Dept/Branch code: 144"` and the last cell to copy where you have `"Total"`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copycolumn()

Dim StartRng As Range, FinishRng As Range, CopyRng As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    Set StartRng = .Columns(1).Find(what:="Dept/Branch code: 144", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If StartRng Is Nothing Then ' check if Find failed
        MsgBox "Unable to Find `Dept/Branch code: 144`", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set FinishRng = .Columns(1).Find(what:="Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If FinishRng Is Nothing Then ' check if Find failed
        MsgBox "Unable to Find `Total`", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' set the range to be copied
    Set CopyRng = .Range(.Cells(StartRng.Row, 1), .Cells(FinishRng.Row, 1))

    ' copy the Range
    CopyRng.Copy Destination:=.Range("C1")

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "dept/branch code" does not have duplicates, you can accomplish what you want in one line

```
Columns(1).Find("*144*", , xlValues, xlWhole).Resize(10).Copy Range("C1")
```